# If A={0} ,Find d(A,ℕ)

Tags: real-analysis

Let (R,d) be the metric space where

d(x,y)=|x−y|∀x,y∈R

IF A={0} , find d(A, ℕ)

What should I try? To but instead the x,y the A always zero and the y (the natural number set ) ? What is it going for ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if $A,B$ are sets, then  $d (A,B) $ means
$$
\inf_{a \in A, b \in B}d (a,b).
$$

Comment: So i just pick the smallest distance?@mees de vries

Comment: Yes, just be careful that in some countries $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ (this is French tradition), but mostly consider $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$, so the answer may vary under different notions.

Comment: @Hasek but the natural set is infinite? What to do ?

Comment: You take $\inf$, not $\sup$, so there is no problem.

Comment: @Hasek i definitely know that , if i not considered a zero in the natural set , the answer would be 1  , that's it , not quite sure about it